# Generate a sublist according to the probability distribution of a list

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

I have a list of elements with their frequency such as:

```
A 3
B 5
C 7
D 8
E 11
```

Now I have to construct a sublist of size 5 out of the elements `A`, `B` and `C` with the elements repeating. How do I calculate the number of times an element should be repeated in the sublist so that the probability distribution of the sublist is the same as (or at least correlates) with the probability distribution of the superset?

To be absolutely clear, in this case, the elements had to be repeated since the sublist should containing 5 elements had to be constructed from 3 elements. There could be a case where a sublist of size 3 has to be constructed from 6 elements as well (in which case lowest probability elements will have to be discarded)